# Sorting Contacts in Android

Tags: android, sorting, contacts

```
    public void ReadContacts() {
    Cursor people = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC ");
    int indexName = people
            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
    int indexNumber = people
            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

    people.moveToFirst();
    do {
        name = people.getString(indexName);
        number = people.getString(indexNumber);

        contacts.put(name, number);

    } while (people.moveToNext());

    printHashMap(contacts);

}

public void printHashMap(HashMap<String, String> a) {

    for (Entry<String, String> lists : a.entrySet()) {
        Log.d(lists.getKey(), lists.getValue());
    }

}
```

The contacts are not sorted inspite of using ASC ? can you help me out with the reason for it ?
I used upper() method also also

Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
        null, null,  "upper("+ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + ") ASC");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put your (sorted) results in a HashMap, which does not preserve the order of elements. Use a List and it will work.

Edit: Using the `Tuple` class you propose in your comment, it should look like this:

```
static class Tuple {
    public String name;
    public String number;

    public Tuple(String name, String number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
    }
}

public void ReadContacts() {
    Cursor people = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,  null, null, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC ");
    int indexName = people
            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
    int indexNumber = people
            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

    List<Tuple> contacts = new ArrayList<Tuple>();

    people.moveToFirst();
    do {
        name = people.getString(indexName);
        number = people.getString(indexNumber);

        contacts.add(new Tuple(name, number));

    } while (people.moveToNext());

    printHashMap(contacts);

}

public void printList(List<Tuple> list) {

    for (Tuple tuple : list) {
        Log.d(tuple.name + ", " + tuple.number);
    }
}
```

But I recommend renaming the `Tuple` class to `Contact` in this case. Having a tuple class with members named 'name' and 'number' is odd.

Comment: there is no such thing as ArrayList<String, String> ?

Comment: ill have to use two different Array Lists ?

Comment: Better use a list of pairs. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Pair.html
Like so: List<Pair<String,String>> myList = new ArrayList<Pair<String,String>>();

Comment: class tuples 
{ 
String x;
String y;
} List<tuples> list = new ArrayList<tuples>(); if i do this then how to add the respective values in x,y

Comment: Use a constructor in your Tuple class. I have updated my answer.